# ASP.NET web config profiles?

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

In my Web.config, under `<system.web>`, I have:

```
<caching>
  <outputCacheSettings>
    <outputCacheProfiles>
      <add name="Cache60Seconds" 
           location="ServerAndClient" 
           duration="60" 
           varyByParam=""
      />
    </outputCacheProfiles>
  </outputCacheSettings>
</caching>
```

In the debug version of this .config, Web.Debug.config, I want the `duration` of the profile "Cache60Seconds" to become 0.

In other words, when I'm developing, I want "Cache60Seconds" to have a duration of 0, so it never caches, and when I release the product, I want the duration to change to 60 seconds. How do I do this?

Comment: Please check this links can really be helpful http://frejnorling.wordpress.com/2011/05/15/automatically-create-different-web-config-files-for-debug-and-release-builds-in-visual-studio-2010/ http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WebDeploymentMadeAwesomeIfYoureUsingXCopyYoureDoingItWrong.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're halfway there with [Web Config Transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx%20%22Web%20Config%20Transformations) however you should setup your Web.Config file to have your typical development environment settings (e.g., set the cache duration to 0) and the in your Web.Release.Config set the appropriate cache duration for your release environment.

Comment: +1 Please note that this is a feature of Visual Studio 2010, and *not* IIS. The transforms are run as part of the packaging procedure... they are not automatically applied anywhere, and the web.release.config file itself is not loaded by IIS